# FormSubmit email arriving blank

Tags: javascript, html, css, form-submit

As the title suggests, the form submit emails sent from my website are arriving but without the name or the email or the body. There are several other posts about this specific issue and none of their solutions worked. Here is what I see : [image: screenshot]
Here is my code :

```html
<div class="right-contact">
  <form action="https://formsubmit.co/[myemail]@gmail.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" class="contact-form">
    <div class="input-control i-c-2">
       <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Your Name">
       <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Your Email">
    </div>
    <div class="input-control">
      <input type="text" name="Subject" required placeholder="Subject...">
     </div>
     <div class="input-control">
     <textarea name="Description" id="" cols="15" rows="8" placeholder="Description..."></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="container-submit-download">
     <div class="submit-btn">
       <button class="main-btn send-email-btn" type="submit">
        <span class="btn-text">Submit</span>
        <span class="btn-icon">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i>
        </span>
       </button>
     </div>
</div>
```

I've also read on one of the posts that the javascript might be wipping the content of the body so here is my js code :

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSection = document.querySelector('.main-content');


function PageTransitions() {
  // Button click active class
  for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
    sectBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
      currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn', '');
      this.className += ' active-btn';
      // Both of these work
      // this.className += ' active-btn';  Here we added a space between the  ' and the 
      class(active - btn)
      // sectBtn[i].classList.add("active-btn");  Here we use the 'classList' to add a new 
      class to an HTML element
    })
  }

  // Section Active
  allSection.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    if (id) {
      // Remove selected from other btns (buttons)
      sectBtn.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove('active');
      })
      e.target.classList.add('active');

      // Hide other sections
      sections.forEach((section) => {
        section.classList.remove('active');
      })

      const element = document.getElementById(id);
      element.classList.add('active');
    }
  })

  // Toggle Theme

  const thmeBtn = document.querySelector('.theme-btn');
  thmeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle('light-mode');
  })
}

PageTransitions();
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank :)

Comment: `enctype="text/plain"` seems wrong. Forms should either be `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of `formsubmit.co`?

Comment: yes, i do : https://formsubmit.co/documentation

Comment: Aside: don't use `.className.replace()`. Use `.classList.remove()`

Comment: Your input names don't match the documentation. `name="Subject"` should be `name="_subject"`, and so on.

Comment: I don't see anything there about how to fill in the message body.

Comment: They have an example [here](https://formsubmit.co/live-demo), so try copying that and building on it. They also have  a FAQ.

Comment: You were right @Barmar, it worked when I replaced "text/plain" with "multipart/form-data". Thank you so much. If you want write an answer so i can put that green tick on it. Thanks to all who helped me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two standard encoding formats for browser form submission: multi-part (which is mormally only used when uploading files) and URL-encoded. `enctype="text/plain"` is not a standard format.

The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you can just omit the `enctype` attribute of the form. If you want to send in multi-part format, you would use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.